# Are left multiplication and adjoint action on itself homogeneous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I feel like I can go some more steps in the proof of $\phi_1$ but can't find a way. Is my logic ok?

My thought is that:

For $\phi_1$, I need to check if $\phi(h_1h_2) = \phi(h_1)\phi(h_2)$ where $h_1, h_2 \in G$

LHS: $g(h_1h_2) = (gh_1)h_2$ by associative property of group.

RHS: $gh_1gh_2 = (gh_1)gh_2$.

Since $h_2 \neq gh_2, \phi_1$ is not homomorphism.

For $\phi_2$,

LHS: $g(h_1h_2)g^{-1} = (gh_1)h_2g^{-1}$

RHS: $gh_1g^{-1}gh_2g^{-1} = (gh_1)h_2g^{-1}$

So, $\phi_2$ is homomorphism.

Comment: Every looks fine, $\phi_1$ is not homomorphism.

Comment: nice. Thank you !

Comment: Since everything is alright, as a bonus you can prove that both are bijections and hence $\phi_2$ is actually an automorphism of $G$, and that $\{\phi_2, g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of the group of all the automorphisms of $G$.

Comment: @user750041 Thanks for the advice!